# Writing procedures for multi-tenant database, schema as variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, schema, prepared-statement, multi-tenant

I am designing a multi-tenant database. Many actions that are needed on a per-tenant basis have been written as stored procedures. Almost all of them use dynamic SQL execution since I have not found a way to differentiate between the schemas other than with dynamic statements.

```
EXEC( 'SELECT * FROM ' + @SchemaName + '.Contacts' )
```

Is there any way to create a variable representing the schema so I can call the select statements without building them dynamically?

```
SELECT * FROM @TheSchema.Contacts
```

SQL Server 2008

Comment: What does @TheSchema really represent here? A custom schema, or a database name and a schema name?

Comment: Just the schema. The database is implied by the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW I have found it much more useful to separate customers by database than by schema. Reasons?

1. All schemas can have identical procedures, thus derive them from model instead of having to create anything. Deployment to multiple databases is no more complex than deployment to multiple schemas, actually less so I'd argue, and the only difference is the application would have to know which database to reference instead of which schema.
2. Different customers can have different recovery models, be backed up on different schedules, etc. This can improve your backup/restore plan especially as the data set gets larger.
3. Having each customer in a separate database makes it very easy to move a tenant to a different server if they get too big for the current one. Extracting the data and objects for their schema only will be quite convoluted.
4. Some customers may legally and/or contractually require that you not store their data in the same database as other customers.

Comment: While I appreciate the feedback, the choice has already been made. And not by me. I'm simply trying to find a way to make the procedures easier to use.

Comment: Well you can't use variables for top-level entities such as databases, schemas, tables and columns, so outside of dynamic SQL (or generating your scripts externally by replacing tokens using PowerShell, C# etc.) I don't know that there's a way to do this...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to keep the stored procedure in each of the tenant databases and execute it inside them.

Comment: If I were writing a stored procedure to actually create the schema and tables within it I couldn't do that. Any suggestions for that scenario?

Comment: @Sparafusile Why would it be such a bad thing for the metadata-creating procedures to use dynamic SQL?

Comment: @Sprafusile, Typically you create a Tenant Database using a DB Script file. Not through a Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand I'm not saying there's anything wrong with it, just wondering if there's an alternative. srini.venigalla it's multi-tenant schemas, not databases.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but I am looking into this option as a cost savings measure - since many cloud providers charge per database and the costs associated with storage are less - especially useful for multi-tenant small databases.

From what I understand, a default schema can be set for the login, thus, setting a schema per login would automatically use that schema for all queries and sprocs. Something to consider for those that comes across this question.

Comment: That's a good point and something I was aware of. My question is more geared towards maintenance scripts where you might need to loop through the list of schemas and add a column to a specific table for example.